# Ubuntu 23.10 freeze and audio loop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, freeze, crash

I dont know much about linux, logs show this error:

> [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000500] Failed to grab modeset ownership

My GPU is a GTX 1050ti and 545 driver, kernel 6.5.0-17-generic.
I experience these freezes with other distros too (manjaro,pop os,debian...) and I have also set the parameter `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` in grub's configuration file.

I really want to use linux on a daily basis, but I cannot.
I'm stuck with Windows which (for some reason) works without any problem.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the proprietary drivers?

Comment: Are you using X11 or Wayland? Do you still have the issue when using X11?

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-21-10-failed-to-grab-modeset-ownership-with-495-44/193867/66

Comment: i didnt because i thought ubuntu did that already at the installation, both x11 and wayland crash the same way, they run fine for a couple of minutes